# android - How to set the button params in the Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I added the Button has footer view of the List view pro-grammatically. Now i want to set the params of the button and set the button gravity as center vertical. I did in the following way but it's not working.How to implement this?

```
    btnMoreUpcomingExits = new Button(this);
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setText("More Upcoming Exits");
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.moreupebtn_widget);
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    btnMoreUpcomingExits.setOnClickListener(btnMoreUpcomingExitsListener);
    getListView().addFooterView(btnMoreUpcomingExits); 
    setListAdapter(new UpcomingExitsResultsListViewAdapter(this));
```

Comment: your listview is under Linear or Relative Layout??

Comment: are you using relative layout in list view ??

Comment: :Yes, i used for the list item.

Comment: do you have tried
    .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER).

Answer (score 0):

You currently have

```
btnMoreUpcomingExits.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

I assume this is an oversight and you meant CENTER_VERTICAL? This will vertically align the text inside the button which it should already be doing so your question seems confusing. Are you instead asking how to align the button itself vertically? If so you need to set the gravity on the buttons parent.

As for the params, you are already setting layout params. What else are you trying to do? You should aim to be more specific in your questions so it is easier to identify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here Gravity in the sense i want to set the button as "Center_Horizontal"(like layout_gravity).Params in the sense in my case it is considered as fill_parent now i want to set it as wrap_content. i think now it will be clear to you?

Comment: Sorry, I am still unsure of what you are asking. Would it be possible to create an image to describe your desired look? That would likely resolve any confusion. Using a tool would likely be best for making an image should you choose to do that. Here is a thread with some wireframing tools you could use to prototype your desired look quickly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929875/gui-design-tools-to-mock-up-iphone-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

Check this this it might help you.

[Check this link](http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=876)

you might use `WindowManager.LayoutParams` to set attribute of `button` in `listview`.

Comment: Also check this link:                         https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/U5pW9b06ikM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits = new Button(this);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setText("More Upcoming Exits");
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.moreupebtn_widget);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setLayoutParams(params);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            layout.addView(btnMoreUpcomingExits);
            btnMoreUpcomingExits.setOnClickListener(btnMoreUpcomingExitsListener);
            getListView().addFooterView(btnMoreUpcomingExits); 
            setListAdapter(new UpcomingExitsResultsListViewAdapter(this));
```

Comment: it's not working i got the this exception 07-11 18:23:52.301: I/System.out(13207): Error from WSResponse:java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: Dont add getListView().addFooterView(btnMoreUpcomingExits); add list and button under layout and set  params of button as i have done

Comment: you want to params of button na...than insert listview and button at bottom of layout.and then set param of button and add button into the layout.